# DNS and mail server: how to setup SPF properly?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, sendmail

Here's my problem: I have my server that does everything: webserver and sendmails, let's call him "**hqf.com**". My client bought another domain, let's call it "**fly.com**".

I need to send "validation emails" that look like this:

```
From: Fly <contact@www.fly.com>
Subject: Registration confirmation
Body: To validate your registration, click on the following link:
http://www.fly.com/register-validate/bb4d5-5b2036d6765f/
```

I've setup a postfix mailserver. When this server sends the email, it's "under the name" **hqf.com**. So all the destinations that accept this email show it like "Fly contact@www.Fly.com *via* hqf.com".

I want to remove the "`via hqf.com`". I've read tons of questions/answers here, and the solution should be to add an "*SPF record*". I'm looking for an example ***with names*** because the ["official SPF sample" here](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Examples) doesn't give names.

Where to put "`mail.acme.example.net.  TXT  "v=spf1 a -all"`"? In my **hqf.com** DNS configuration or in **fly.com**?

Where to put "`example.com.  TXT  "v=spf1 a:mail.example.com -all"`"? In my **hqf.com** DNS configuration or in **fly.com**?

The sample is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use `example.com` for your client and `example.net for your mail server's domain.

Your client's mail should be sent by an address like `donotreply@example.com`.  Other than `example.com` your client would have SPF records like `v=spf1 -all`.  As `example.com` send email using the the mail servers for `example.net` it would have an SPF record like `v-spf1 -mx -all` or `v=spf1 -a:mail.example.net`. The first assumes the your client's email specifies your mail sever as and `MX`.

Your servers should be configured the same. You will have more delivery successes if your mail server has a `PTR` record returning its address, as well as an `A` record.  This should pass reverse DNS validation.  Sending using a dedicated mail FQDN such as `mail.example.net` rather than your registered domain is traditional.  Few legitimate servers use simple domains like `example.net`.

Answer (score 0):

If hqf.com has mail, it likely already has an SPF record. If you are using the same server to send mail for fly.com, you can use the `include=hqf.com` in a SPF record for fly.com.

You do need an SPF for each domain you send mail "envelope From:"